# Euro (€) in imagettftext

Tags: php, imagettftext

How can i create an € sign with `imagettftext()`?
I'm using the font 'Lucida Grande' which contains the euro sign.
`&euro;` does not work, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) (emphasis mine):

> The text string in UTF-8 encoding.
>
> **May include decimal numeric character references (of the form:
>   `&#8364;`) to access characters in a font beyond position 127.** The
>   hexadecimal format (like `&#xA9;`) is supported. Strings in UTF-8
>   encoding can be passed directly.
>
> **Named entities, such as `&copy;`, are not supported**. Consider using
>   html_entity_decode() to decode these named entities into UTF-8 strings
>   (html_entity_decode() supports this as of PHP 5.0.0).
>
> If a character is used in the string which is not supported by the
>   font, a hollow rectangle will replace the character.

You can try using the actual € character, or decoding it, or using the decimal character reference.  See here for the entry in FileFormat.Info Unicode Lookup, which has all the code formats: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm.  In this case it would be `&#8364;`.